# Is activity title or name visible to users in recent apps screen?

Tags: android

Is activity title or name visible to users in recent apps screen in some version of android?

Comment: Yes it is displayed.

Comment: @kevz which version ,can you point to some documentation?

Comment: Which version? I think it is displayed in all version of Android.

Comment: @Andrain      activity name is visible or title?

Comment: It is the Application name that is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the application name that is visible to user. No matter what the title is!

You can set it from AndroidManifest.xml in the `application` section. [Reference.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label)

```
<application>
    android:label="App name here" 
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: If i give a activity label will it override the app label in the recent app screen?

Comment: Yes it will override the app label!

Comment: Did little research and it seems that only the main activity's label specified in the AndroidManifest.xml will change the name in the recent app screen so be careful :)

Comment: So to wrap it up: Only applications label or main activitys label will change the name in the recent app screen.

Comment: @vilpe89 There's one more way: [`Activity.setTaskDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)), since Lolliopop.